# Trouble with dropdown menu jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm really new with JS and Jquery, and I'm trying to make a dropdown menu using slideDown, but things go a little wrong when I hover the mouse quickly a lot of times in the parent link.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('li.parent').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.sub').slideDown('fast')
  });

  $('li.parent').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.sub').slideUp('fast')
  });
});
```

And the HTML

```
 <li class="parent">
   <span>Produtos</span>
    <ul class="sub">
    <div class="sub-bg">
        <li>
          <a href='produtos.php?categoria=9'>Banho</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='produtos.php?categoria=7'>Cama</a>
        </li>
     </div>
    </ul>
   </li>
```

And [here](http://viotidesign.com.br/clientes/casafelice/) is the online website, so you guys can see the problem, just hover quickly in the "Produtos" buton..

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the online website?

Comment: Forgot in the first post, edited now... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not guess wrong about your problem, you just need to use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) which will `stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements` and it should be fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('li.parent').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.sub').stop().slideDown('fast')
    });

    $('li.parent').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.sub').stop().slideUp('fast')
    });
});​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vGuHh/

Comment: Thanks, that's my first try but I don't know why, when using `stop()` if I hover quickly the submenu stop to appear as you can see [here](http://viotidesign.com.br/clientes/casafelice/).